# Cannot convert an indexed (logical) image to grayscale

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

```
          Filename: '/bmp/ae07_001.bmp'
       FileModDate: '09-Apr-2014 19:21:20'
          FileSize: 7202
            Format: 'bmp'
     FormatVersion: 'Version 3 (Microsoft Windows 3.x)'
             Width: 449
            Height: 119
          BitDepth: 1
         ColorType: 'indexed'
   FormatSignature: 'BM'
NumColormapEntries: 2
          Colormap: [2x3 double]
           RedMask: []
         GreenMask: []
          BlueMask: []
   ImageDataOffset: 62
  BitmapHeaderSize: 40
         NumPlanes: 1
   CompressionType: 'none'
        BitmapSize: 7140
    HorzResolution: 2925
    VertResolution: 2925
     NumColorsUsed: 2
NumImportantColors: 2
```

So its an indexed image of logical format.

The problem is that I cannot read it in. For example if I use the simple command

`img = imread(file);`

I get this:

[image]

So to read it in properly I use:

```
[img, map] = imread(file);
imshow(img, map);
```

Here it shows up fine, as it should, but I do not want to show it, I want to work on it further so I have to convert it to grayscale, which I do using this command:

`new = ind2gray(img, map);`

Here I am presented with the warning:

> Warning: X should be a double, single, uint8, or uint16 array. 
>   Convert your image to double using IM2DOUBLE(X,'INDEXED').

And if I use `imshow(new)` it just shows up as a blank box, just a white image without the text.

I tried the recommended `im2double(img, 'indexed')` and then use `ind2gray` but again I am presented with a white box, with the data missing.

Why cant I convert this image to grayscale?

Comment: Can you post the actual bmp somewhere without modifications?  That said, given your results, I bet you could get what you want by `uint8(255*~imread(file))` or `double(~imread(file))`, but that would be an ad hoc solution.  Perhaps just `new = ind2gray(uint8(img), map);` would be the correct answer for a binary indexed image (weird)

Comment: If the data in the array are either 0 or 1, why can't you just do something like `img = 255 * uint8(img);`? What is the type that `imread()` is returning and what is the type you are trying to get to?

Comment: @chappjc Your ad-hoc solution did get the job done. Thank you, if you could add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Great!  Answer posted.  Glad it helped.

Comment: I'm still curious about this binary indexed .bmp file.  Any way to post the actual file without modification?  The ones in the post are converted to png and jpg.

Comment: Oh right sorry. I forgot about that. I'll post it tomorrow when I get back to work.

Comment: @chappjc File uploaded here: https://mega.co.nz/#!CIM1EJDQ!A2Z7u6JCUj6ggt5IvCB_dxIMyzXNLlkNPJmWa0qUz0I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a binary indexed image, and when you display the indexes as an intensity image it is backwards, you just have to invert those intensities:

```
uint8(255*~imread(file))
```

or

```
double(~imread(file))
```